# bitbake error package not found in base feeds

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to include https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ndeflib in my image. Thus I created a recipe for this. Following are the contents of *python-ndeflib_0.2.0.bb*

```
DESCRIPTION = "NFC Data Exchange Format decoder and encoder."
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/0c/0f/b9d94cee7847697469c49a25b4d23236de534451990b83008e6bf4fab15b/ndeflib-0.2.0.tar.gz"

do_install_append() {
    rm -f ${D}${libdir}/python*/site-packages/site.py*
}

do_compile_prepend() {
    ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/python setup.py install ${DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS} || \
    true
}
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "b7ae0c34f49289c44c292e24843cfeb1"
```

I am able to **bitbake python-ndeflib** successfully

but whenever I try to build my final os image **bitbake fsl-image-machine-test**
the process fails at the with following error

```
ERROR: python-ndeflib not found in the base feeds
```

Thus where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to write a recipe similar to the one in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729465/src-uri-not-working-in-bitabake-recipe)question? That should have solved your issue.

Writing something similar to that recipe, gives you `python3-ndeflib_0.2.0.bb`:

```
DESCRIPTION = "NFC Data Exchange Format decoder and encoder."
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "ISC"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=f7c92777f3af9604e192a0d195b6a6a4"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "b7ae0c34f49289c44c292e24843cfeb1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "baa86a48cf310cf77524f6fa04f5bd90775c4c290116b6b543aa3d6d65b721bf"

inherit pypi setuptools3
```

Which seems to work pretty well. Note that I used Python 3 instead of two (`setuptools3`).

Ie inherit `setuptools` or `setuptools3` instead of writing your own `do_compile`, `do_install`, etc, unless you really have to.

Comment: problem was including my own do_compile and do_install.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error (*projectname* not found in base feeds in do_rootfs)solved in different project (non cmake , non make) with this:

> ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"

in its *.bb file.

Some other people has this error because they were using capital letters in project name.